Spring Boot graphql endpoint keeps coming up 404
I am having trouble with a spring boot web graphql API project endpoint that keeps returning a 404 not found error message. My controller looks like this:
package com.pdrake.graphqlnfc.controllers

import com.pdrake.graphqlnfc.entities.movie.Movie
import com.pdrake.graphqlnfc.repositories.MovieRepository
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller

@Controller
class MovieController(
    private val movieRepository: MovieRepository
) {
    @QueryMapping
    fun movies(): List<Movie> {
        return movieRepository.findAll()
    }
}

My application.yml file looks like this.
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:default
    password: *******
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  graphql:
    graphiql:
      enabled: true
    cors:
      allowed-origins: "http://localhost:8080"
      allowed-headers: "*"
      allowed-methods: GET, POST
  security:
    user:
      name: *******
      password: *******


My schema looks like this
schema {
    query: Query
}
type Query {
    movies: [Movie]!
    movieById(id: ID!): Movie
}

type Movie {
    id: ID
    name: String!
    description: String!
    genres: [Genre]!
    cast: [Cast]!
}

type Genre {
    id: ID
    name: String!
}

type Cast {
    id: ID
    name: String!
    age: Int!

}

As well as a security configuration class
package com.pdrake.graphqlnfc.config

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests {
            it.anyRequest().permitAll()
        }.csrf {
            it.disable()
        }.sessionManagement {
            it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        }
        return http.build()
    }
}

I have a build.gradle file that looks like this
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.9.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.9.22'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.9.22'
}

group = 'com.pdrake'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Xjsr305=strict'
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


I originally thought it was a security issue so I created the filterChain bean, and that didn't do anything. I saw something on the online that says you need to implement an interface in your controller class, however that is in conflict with the official documentation that says all you have to do is annotate your class with @Controller. So basically I am completely out of ideas.

Can you provide a reproductible example on github ?
